# 1/6 Clock Frequency Divider

Tags: frequency, clock, flipflop

How would I design a circuit made of rising edge triggered flip flops and inverters to make its output 1/6 of the clock frequency. 
[image: This is what I was thinking]
Cheers

Comment: So what is wrong with the circuit on your(?) drawing?

Comment: The solution is a 3 bit Johnson counter, which is already displayed in your question.

Answer (score 3):

We don't just outright give answers to homework problems here, but will help you to solve them yourself if you cooperate.

First, take the prime factors of 6 to see if the problem can be broken up and simplified.  Powers or 2 can be directly realized by binary counters.

The factor of 3 makes this more interesting.  3 is a low number, so one option is a chain of flip-flops.  Other ways to divide by arbitrary numbers is to use a binary counter, then reset it when it gets to a certain value.  Look up something called a *divide by N* counter.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was just looking for some direction not so much the solution. Now I know for next time.

Answer (score 0):

The indicated circuit, with the clocks of all the flip flops wired together, is likely to generate a square wave output of the desired frequency.  There is a potential problem with it, however, that might cause it to output 1/2 of the input frequency rather than 1/6.  Can you see what might cause it to output the wrong frequency, and replacing the inverter with something else might help cure the problem?